# SharePoint 2019 Product Configuration Wizard fails. Error: Must declare the scalar variable "@newViewUID"

Tags: 2019, configuration-wizard

[image]

After the latest updates in September 2020 I couldn't succeed to complete SharePoint Product Configuration Wizard on my developing machine. We get the following error on database upgrade phase (see attachment photo).

Error: Must declare the scalar variable "@newViewUID".

My Machine Configuration:
Windows Server 2019 - MSSQL Server 2017 - SharePoint 2019

We have tried to upgrade Databases through PowerShell and we got the same error. Also same error when we add New Content Database through Central Administration.

Today I have build new machine with Configuration.
Windows Server 2019 - MSSQL Server 2019 - SharePoint 2019

I Install MSSQL Server 2019, SharePoint 2019 successfully. I have done the updates and run Configuration wizard. Faced with same Error.

Error: Must declare the scalar variable "@newViewUID"

I appreciate for any help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found what is causing the issue!
It's because of MSSQL Server in Turkish collation. After SharePoint September 2020 updates SharePoint Configuration wizard fails.

Here is what I did to find the issue:
I have build up new system:
Windows Server 2019 - MSSQL Server 2019 - SharePoint 2019

During Setup of MSSQL server I change default Collation(Turkish_CI_AS) to Latin1_General_CI_AS_KS_WS and everything works fine. Configuration wizard succeed! Databases successfully Upgraded!

Hoping to help someone having the same issue.